# ARM Subroutine call and Link Register Usage

Tags: assembly, arm

Every functional call resulting in a creation of the stack frame and current PC value is pushed onto the stack. While unwinding the stack during the function return, the PC value (return address) can be loaded onto the PC from the stack frame. If so, what is the need for Link register (LR).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to design a processor without a link register.  An example for such an architecture is x86 where function calls directly push the return address on the stack and function returns directly pick the return address off the stack.

Having a link register is just a different choice for this design.  While not a particularly novel idea (e.g. 1960's IBM S/360 already had this concept), link registers have been popularised by the RISC processor design school as they reduce the complexity of the function call and return instructions, making the processor easier to design and possibly faster due to the reduced number of transistors required.

Another advantage of link registers is that functions that do not call other functions (leaf functions) can get away with not storing the return address on the stack at all.  This saves a load and a store each time the function is executed, which can be a significant time save when the function is short.

Comment: Increasing or having enough registers so that you can store the first few passed parameters and the link register avoids the stack which is a performance cost (vs a stack based parameter and or return address solution).  Leaf functions make this even nicer if they use few variables (need no stack at all).  Depending on the architecture once you commit to a stack access the one extra clock cycle to say save 4 registers instead of 2 is not as much of a burden as the overhead for doing an access in general.  I think it is memory accesses not transistors...

Comment: @old_timer You can actually get rid of the memory accesses using a stack engine or memory operand renaming.  And usually, you push the return address anyway, so combining this with a call can save time on simplistic processor designs (you get something to fill that nasty branch delay slot with).  It is however a bit more complex to design.

Comment: tbe idea behind risc in general is to avoid or reduce memory accesses by increasing the number of general purpose registers and simplifying so that many things can be done in registers without needing memory accesses.

Comment: the reduction of logic in risc comes from the simplification of the instructions, fewer state machines needed (no microcoding needed plus risc like state machines for the microcode) etc.  memory accesses are same same with a cisc vs risc, similar state machine you kick off and wait for

Comment: Excellent concise answer though.  For whatever reason the desire is to use registers instead of a stack frame because sometimes you can avoid the stack frame in part or all together.

Answer (score 0):

When BL or BLX is executed, the return address is stored in the link register. This way the return address can be accessed so that it may be pushed onto the stack (instead of a call instruction that pushes directly).

```
myfunc:
 push {lr} ;saves return address
 ...
 pop {pc} ; returns to saved value
```

In leaf functions (no further subcalls), there is no need to save the return address. The return is just implemented by jumping to the address in the link register:

`bx    lr`